# How do i fix not being able to destroy blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I log into my minecraft as normal. then I get into a single player world so I can get lag out of the way to get into a normal multiplayer server. so I get mst of the lag out then I go in f5 to check my skin and punch in air. my player doesn't punch. I check the mouse settings. there normal. then im like its just for sp. I got to a server same thing. so please if you know if its my client or is it mouse settings because I cant play my game if I cant destroy blocks.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your mouse settings?

Comment: Are you possible in adventure mode?

Answer (score -2):

I think it is internal server lag because this has happened to me before. i allocated more RAM and the problem went away